# How to find calculated population in dax formula

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with `country` and `population for 2017`, and I have another table with `country` and `population growth rate%`. And I have one table with `years` like (2018 to 2028). I am trying to find calculated population for 10 years on the basis of these data as we are calculating compound interest.

Comment: Is the growth rate expected to be constant for the whole 10 years?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are working with growth rates, it is very unlikely that you will want to do this calculation as a measure.  Rates don't aggregate well.

So, the first thing you're going to want to do is get your data into one table.  I would do this in query editor.

You'll need a Cartesian join between your list of countries and a list of years.  The PowerBI method for this is a little non-intuitive.  You add a custom column, and in the formula you just type in the name of the table.
The result is that every single row in the countries table will be matched with every single row from the years table.  If you have 5 rows in one and 10 rows in the other, the resulting table is 50 rows.

[image]

Then Merge in your table with the growth rates.  Now you have a table that has the name of the country, the 2017 starting population, the growth rate.  This set of rows will be repeated for every year from 2018 - 2028.

There is a specific formula for cumulative (compounded) growth.

```
Pricipal * ( 1 + RatePerPeriod / NumberOfCompoundsPerPeriod) ^ (NumberOfPeriods * NumberOfCompoundsPerPeriod)
```

You're doing this annually, so it simplifies a bit

```
Pricipal * ( 1 + Rate) ^ (NumberOfYears)
```

And the M will look like this:

```
[2017 Population] * Number.Power((1 + [Growth]),([Year] - 2016))
```

Good Luck!  Hope it helps.
[image]